# Problem when redirecting my output zone (C program)

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that compares the output of two commands with the following sample :

compare command1 [arguments...] -- command2 [arguments...]

I have to redirect those two outputs to two files A and B and then use diff -u to compare

Here is my code up to now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//Create a process to execute the first command (argv[1]) with its arguments (until you find "--") and redirect it to a file A. Then, from the argument after "--", to the end, execute the second command with its arguments and redirect it to file B.
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int fd1, fd2;
    pid_t pid;
    int i = 1;
    char* args1[10];
    char* args2[10];
    while(strcmp(argv[i], "--") != 0){
        args1[i-1] = argv[i];
        i++;
    }
    args1[i-1] = NULL;
    i++;
    int j = 0;
    while(i < argc){
        args2[j] = argv[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    args2[j] = NULL;
    fd1 = open("A", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    fd2 = open("B", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        dup2(fd1, 1);
        close(fd1);
        close(fd2);
        execvp(args1[0], args1);
    }
    else{
        wait(NULL);
        dup2(fd2, 1);
        close(fd1);
        close(fd2);
        execvp(args2[0], args2);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

So, the part where i redirect the outputs of the commands works perfectly (A and B files are filled , even when I give parameters) but then I gave up on using diff -u for now (or anything) because my console output doesn't seem to be used anymore. No matter what I do or where i put a debug printf, it doesnt appeear on the console when compiling and viewing on terminal, so I guess the standard output is now one of those two files, but I don't know how to put it back on the console.

Tried debugging many times, tried dup...

Comment: You need *two* child-processes, one for each program. I suggest you create a function to fork a child process, set up the redirection, and execute the program. The parent process waits for both child-processes to exit, and then does the comparison.

Comment: That's what I did before but for some reason, when I did that, the B file wasn't created so I re-worked it and this time both files work but my problem is elsewhere aha